# Typesetting a covector

Tags: notation

I understand the notation of upper and lower indices for components of vectors and covectors, but when I write a vector *not* in component form I use an over-arrow notation e.g. $\vec r$.  Is there a standard notation for covectors?  An under-arrow?  A left arrow?

Comment: I don't think there is a companion to $\vec{(\cdot)}$ (or boldface, or underline, or wavey underline, ...) for covectors.  You can borrow the bra-ket convention from theoretical physics if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Covectors are also vectors so they can also be typeset with an arrow overhead. They are usually distinguished from vectors by using the greek alphabet.

> So $\vec v$ for a vector

> And $\vec \alpha$ for a covector.

Having said this, I've never seen covectors being notated in this way.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  The covector lives in the dual space.  I may make an identification of the covector with a vector in the vector space e.g.  $f^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}f_\nu$, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @Kieran Mullen: Given a vector space $V$, the dual space $V^*$ is *also* a vector space. It's obviously not the same space as the original space, that is $V$ is not the same as $V^*$, nevertheless, $V^*$ is *a* vector space.